# Doctrine : Class Table Inheritance : Add an existing object from parent table to extended table

Tags: php, mysql, symfony, doctrine-orm, doctrine

Using the exemple provided by doctrine [documentation](http://docs.doctrine-project.org/projects/doctrine-orm/en/latest/reference/inheritance-mapping.html#class-table-inheritance)

```
<?php
namespace MyProject\Model;

/**
 * @Entity
 * @InheritanceType("JOINED")
 * @DiscriminatorColumn(name="discr", type="string")
 * @DiscriminatorMap({"person" = "Person", "employee" = "Employee"})
 */
 class Person
{
    // ...
}

/** @Entity */
class Employee extends Person
{
    // ...
}
```

Assuming that i have an existing object Person. I wish to promote this Person as Employee. I can't find a way to do that. I tried to add a OneToOne relationship and create setPerson or setUser methods.

```
$employee = new Employee();
$employee->setRole('ROLE_EMPLOYEE');
$employee->setPerson($person);
```

OR

```
$employee = new Employee();
$employee->setRole('ROLE_EMPLOYEE');
$person->setEmployee($employee);
```

For sure i didn't manage to make this work and can't find another way to do it. The only way that could work is to delete the object person and create a new employee with previous person's data.

Any hints or solutions?

Comment: I faced a same problem and I decide to do it with raw SQL queries ... changing the discr manually

Comment: @Alsatian Thank you. I though about that too. Good you manage to do it that way. I'll do that while waiting for another solution in case there is one. If you want to post it as an answer i'll be glad to upvote it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Doctrine dont allow to change types on the fly, why?:

if u create Person object its should be Person to the end, for example if employee will have some extra fields and u would downgrade it to Person, u lost Employee fields. Thats why u should create new object.

inheritance was created only to map OOP Inheritance to database, use it if u want some extra fields in child entity.

But if u still want to change discr u may use:

```
$em->getConnection()->exec( "UPDATE Person SET discr = 'employee' WHERE id = ".$entity->getId() );
```

Comment: Alright, thank you for the answer. but then the next step is use raw SQL queries as mentioned by @Alsatian to create the user in the employee table, isn't it?